# SQL Server Reporting Services CSV Report Export Option Missing

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have an installation of SQL Server Express 2016 SP1. I cannot find nor enable the option to export reports that are run from the web as CSV files.

I have tried a couple of times to modify rsreportserver.config with different Render options under the key //, restart my SQL Server Reporting Services instance each time. The extension keys I've tried are:

(This is the default that comes with the Server)

```
<Extension Name="CSV" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering"/>
```

(This one causes the SQL Server Reporting Server service to not start)

```
<Extension Name="CSV" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.CsvRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.CsvRendering"/>
```

The thing that is confusing me is that we were running SQL Express 2012 before reimaging our server, and we could export to CSV with that version. Am I missing something here, do I have the wrong XML key?

Comment: Express edition has limitations in export formats. It allows document formats like EXCEL and PDF but not others like CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, and a couple of in place upgrades. It is true that Express is incapable of outputting CSV files. I upgraded a couple of test SQL Server environments to Developer edition and the option now appears.